# More than one maximum value in SQL

Tags: sql, database, subquery, max

I need to write a query that searches for a maximum value and if there more items having the same maximum value, it would return them both.
For example, if I have in my database

```
Item     Price
Coffee   2.50
Tea      2.50
Cola     1.50
```

it would give Coffee and Tea as an answer.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is typically solved using a window function:

```
select item, 
       price
from (
  select item,
         price, 
         dense_rank() over (order by price desc) as rnk
  from the_table
) t 
where rnk = 1;
```

You didn't specify your DBMS, therefore the above is standard (ANSI) SQL.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively ...

```
SELECT 
    Item,
    Price
FROM the_table 
WHERE Price = (SELECT MAX(Price) FROM the_table)
```

Or ...

```
SELECT 
    Item,
    Price
FROM the_table 
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT Price 
    FROM the_table st
    WHERE st.Price > the_table.Price
  )
```

Or one more ...

```
SELECT 
    Item,
    Price
FROM 
    the_table 
     INNER JOIN 
      (
        SELECT MAX(Price) MaxPrice
        FROM the_table 
      ) Match ON 
        the_table.Price = match.MaxPrice
```

Just in case windowed functions aren't available.